# How to open two link simultaneously in same tab without alerting or redirecting the first one

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have to open two link within a same tab using JavaScript and HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
go(){
windows.open('http://www.yahoo.com');
}
</script>
a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en-GB"onclick = "go();">click me</a>
```

What I want; when someone clicked on <kbd>click me</kbd> hyperlink then it should automatically runs sign out link of Gmail in background without any alert and redirect the automatically link which is in `windows.open('http://yahoo.com');`.

Comment: not possible unless we are talking about same domains here.

Comment: It Means we can't open in same tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm would be:

1. on click dynamically add a DOM element: 1x1 px image with its source set to GMail logout URL;

   wait a couple of seconds (timer);

   redirect to Yahoo.

Ok, whole test page content would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function go() {
                var oImg=document.createElement("img");
                oImg.setAttribute('src', 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout');
                oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
                oImg.setAttribute('height', '1px');
                oImg.setAttribute('width', '1px');
                document.body.appendChild(oImg);
                var t=setTimeout("goOn()",1500);
            }
            function goOn() {
                window.location.assign("http://yahoo.com");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="go();return false;">superlink</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Have tested it in FFox - works fine : )

Answer (score 0):

A best way is to create a assincronous call to logout from wherever you want

try use jQuery get method or this tutorial: http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html